# How to obtain Asymptotic Expansion of a given function

Tags: functions, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Today I was playing with this function
$$
\sqrt{1-x}
$$
and I found that if I try to approximate (near $x=0$) such a function with a polynomial of some order then I can find the same coefficients that WolframAlpha find.

Starting with
$$
\sqrt{1-x}\sim a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots
$$
where $\cdots$ are terms of higher power in $x$, I squared both sides obtaining
$$
1-x\sim a_0^2+a_1^2x^2+a_2^2x^4+a_3^2x^6+2a_0a_1x+2a_0a_2x^2+2a_0a_3x^3+2a_1a_2x^3+2a_1a_3x^4+2a_2a_3x^5+\dots
$$
or
$$
1-x\sim a_0^2+2a_0a_1x+(a_1^2+2a_0a_2)x^2+(2a_0a_3+2a_1a_2)x^3+\dots
$$
where I choose to ignore terms $x^n$ with $n>3$. In this way I obtain an "equivalence" between two polynomials and imposing that each term of those polynomials are equal one find
$$
a_0^2=1,\,2a_0a_1=-1,\,a_1^2+2a_0a_2=0,\,2a_0a_3+2a_1a_2=0.
$$
Choosing $a_0=1$ one get
$$
\sqrt{1-x}\sim1-\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{8}x^2-\frac{1}{16}x^3+\cdots.
$$
Is this method correct? I tried and it works also for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ or others irrational and rational functions!
I also would love if someone give some references.

Comment: It is much simpler to use  *Taylor's formula*.  Any way, this is derived from  the standard binomial expansion  for $\;(1+x)^\alpha$ for $\alpha=\frac12$.

Comment: @Bernard Sure it is.But I want to know if it is an accident or if I want the expansion up to a given order this method will help me?

Comment: I think  you'll obtain recurrence relations for the coefficients, in which each coefficient is introduced one at a time, so it should be comparatively easy to work it out.

Comment: Since your starting point is $a_0^2=1$  you could choose $a_0=-1.$ Then you would get $a_1=1/2,$ $a_2=1/8,$ $a_3=1/16, \dots$ and that is the Maclaurin series for $-\sqrt{1-x}.$

Comment: Some references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an accident.
It is a general way
to find the square root
of a power series.

Writing it out:

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n
&=(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i)^2\\
&=(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} a_i x^i)(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_j x^j)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_ia_j x^{i+j}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ia_{n-i}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$c_n
=\sum_{i=0}^{n} a_ia_{n-i}
$.

For $n=0$,
$c_0 = a_0^2$,
so
$a_0 = \sqrt{c_0}$.

For $n > 0$,
if $n = 2m+1$,

$\begin{array}\\
c_n
&=c_{2m+1}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{2m+1} a_ia_{2m+1-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}+\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m+1} a_ia_{2m+1-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_{i+m+1}a_{2m+1-(i+m+1)}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_{i+m+1}a_{m-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_{(m-i)+m+1}a_{i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}+\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_{2m+1-i}a_{i}\\
&=2\sum_{i=0}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}\\
&=2a_0a_{2m+1}+2\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$a_{2m+1}
=\dfrac{c_{2m+1}-2\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_ia_{2m+1-i}}{2a_0}
$.

If $n = 2m$,

$\begin{array}\\
c_n
&=c_{2m}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{2m} a_ia_{2m-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}+a_m^2+\sum_{i=m+1}^{2m} a_ia_{2m-i}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}+a_m^2+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_{i+m+1}a_{2m-(i+m+1)}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}+a_m^2+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_{i+m+1}a_{m-i-1}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}+a_m^2+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_{(m-1-i)+m+1}a_{m-(m-1-i)-1}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}+a_m^2+\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_{2m-i}a_{i}\\
&=2\sum_{i=0}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}+a_m^2\\
&=2a_0a_{2m}+2\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}+a_m^2\\
\end{array}
$

so
$a_{2m}
=\dfrac{c_{2m}-a_m^2-2\sum_{i=1}^{m-1} a_ia_{2m-i}}{2a_0}
$.

Note that we must have
$c_0 \ne 0$
and there are two possible series
for each sign in
$a_0
= \pm \sqrt{c_0}$.

If $c_0 < 0$,
the result requires
complex numbers.

If $c_0 = 1$,
then
$a_0 = \pm 1$.